# RDLC Report is showing nothing

Tags: stored-procedures, rdlc, error-reporting, dynamic-rdlc-generation

This is my stored procedure:

```
IF (@Action = 'selectbyLocationSummary')
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        SUM(INHD.TaxableAmt),
        SUM(INHD.CGSTAmount),
        SUM(INHD.SGSTAmt),
        SUM(INHD.IGSTAmount)
    FROM 
        InvoiceHD AS INHD       
    WHERE 
        INHD.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNczR.png)

I want to show TaxableAmt, CGSTAmount, SGSTAmt, IGSTAmount values on a RDLC report..

Why is the RDLC report not showing anything?